# Allowing WinRM in the Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, powershell, winrm

I am using windows 7 machine, installed windows power shell. How to ensure that the Windows Firewall is configured to allow Windows Remote Management connections from the workstation. For example:
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" profile=public protocol=tcp localport=5985 remoteip=localsubnet new remoteip=any

I'm following above command, but not able to configure it.

Comment: I'm tweaking the question and tags since this has nothing to do with Chef itself and is just about setting up WinRM.

Answer (score 13):

`Enable-PSRemoting -force` Is what you are looking for!

`winrm quickconfig`is good precaution to take as well, starts WinRM Service and sets to service to Auto Start

However if you are looking to do this to all Windows 7 Machines you can enable this via [Group Policy](https://support.auvik.com/hc/en-us/articles/204424994-How-to-enable-WinRM-with-domain-controller-Group-Policy-for-WMI-monitoring)

Comment: winrm quickconfig was necessary part for me.. echo following:  

`The following changes must be made:

Configure LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights remotely to local users.`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which protocol you use.

The following one works for me:

```
Set-NetFirewallRule -Name "WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP-PUBLIC" -RemoteAddress Any
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.2#how-to-enable-remoting-on-public-networks

Answer (score 0):

I used this a few years ago to connect to a remote server and update WinRM before joining it to the domain. (the $server variable is part of a foreach statement).  This part of my script updates -:

1. Windows Firewall from Public to Private
2. Windows Firewall to allow remote WMI Access
3. Trusted Hosts is not domain-joined and therefore must be added to the TrustedHosts list
4. Windows Firewall to allow RDP
5. Enable RDP : 1 = Disable ; 0 = Enable

```
$RequestingServer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
#Local Server Admin Account
[STRING] $LocalUser = "Administrator" #Obviously Change Account
[STRING] $LocalPassword = "Password01" #Obviously Change Password
$LocalSecurePassword = $LocalPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$LocalCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $LocalUser, $LocalSecurePassword

                #Update Windows Firewall Remotely
                $LocalSession = New-PSSession -Computername $Server -Credential $LocalCredentials
                Invoke-Command -Session $LocalSession -ScriptBlock {
                
                $AddServer = $Using:RequestingServer
                
                #Update Windows Firewall from Public to Private
                Get-NetConnectionProfile | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
                #Update Windows Firewall to allow remote WMI Access
                netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" new enable=yes
                #Update Trusted Hosts is not domain-joined and therefore must be added to the TrustedHosts list 
                Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $AddServer -Force
                #Update Windows Firewall to allow RDP
                Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop"
                #Enable RDP : 1 = Disable ; 0 = Enable
                Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0
                }
```